# Dynamically change datatables column width via API

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I know we can set the columns width on a datatable via the [columns.width](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width) option. But now I want to change that option on the xhr event.

Based on the ajax response I get from the server I want to hide/show a column and adjust the other columns width accordingly (they are all fixed size). Is there any way to achieve that via API?

I looked around all docs but seems it's not possible to achieve.

Comment: Are you loading Datatable after ajax response or It's already loaded and you want to hide/show a column and change the width size of others after ajax response ?

Comment: I'm doing that on xhr event of datatables itself. basically I want to do my changes after all my data retrieval from the server.

Comment: I think it's pretty easy. U can check by if else condition. If foo then show/hide bar and change the width of other columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change settings once the dataTable is initalised. But if you *are* using `column.width` *and* you have turned `autoWidth` off, then the width of each column is easy to change. Here is an example :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   autoWidth: false,
   ajax: {
     url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/avxod'
   },
   columns: [
     { data: 'name', width: 50 },
     { data: 'position', width: 50 },
     { data: 'salary', width: 50 },
     { data: 'office',  width: 50}
  ]    
})  

$('#example').on('xhr.dt', function() {
  $('#example thead th:eq(1)').width('400');
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cc7x6h64/**

It works because `column.width` is injected into each `<th>` as `style="width: xxx;"`